# mongodb 2 level aggregate lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have those collection schemas

```
Schema.users = {
    name : "string",
    username : "string",
    [...]
}

Schema.rooms = {
    name : "string",
    hidden: "boolean",
    user: "string",
    sqmt: "number",
    service: "string"
}

Schema.room_price = {
    morning : "string",
    afternoon: "string",
    day: "string",
    room:'string'
}
```

I need to aggregate the users with the rooms and foreach room the specific room prices.

the expected result would be

```
[{
_id:"xXXXXX",
name:"xyz",
username:"xyz",
rooms:[
  {
    _id: 1111,
    name:'room1',
    sqmt: '123x', 
    service:'ppp',
    room_prices: [{morning: 123, afternoon: 321}]
  }
]}]
```

The first part of the aggregate could be

```
db.collection('users').aggregate([
  {$match: cond},
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'rooms',
    let: {"user_id", "$_id"},
    pipeline: [{$match:{expr: {$eq: ["$user", "$$user_id"]}}}],
    as: "rooms"
  }}])
```

but I can't figure out how to get the room prices within the same aggregate

Comment: What is the relation between `room` and `room_prices` ?

Comment: `_id` in `rooms` and `room` in `room_price`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming that `room` from the `room_prices` collection has the matching data from the `name` of the `rooms` collection, then that would the expression to match on for the "inner" pipeline of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) expression with yet another [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

```
  db.collection('users').aggregate([
    { $match: cond },
    { $lookup: {
      from: 'rooms',
      let: { "user_id": "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
       { $match:{ $expr: { $eq: ["$user", "$$user_id"] } } },
       { $lookup: {
         from: 'room_prices',
         let: { 'name': '$name' },
         pipeline: [
           { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$room', '$$name'] } } },
           { $project: { _id: 0, morning: 1, afternoon: 1 } }
         ],
         as: 'room_prices'
       }}
      ],
      as: "rooms"
    }}
  ])
```

That's also adding a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in there to select only the fields you want from the prices. When using the expressive form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you actually do get to express a "pipeline", which can be any aggregation pipeline combination. This allows for complex manipulation and such "nested lookups".

Note that using mongoose you can also get the collection name from the model object using something like:

```
 from: RoomPrice.collection.name
```

This is generally future proofing against possible model configuration changes which might possibly change the name of the underlying collection.

---

You can also do pretty much the same with the "legacy" form of `$lookup` prior to the sub-pipeline syntax available from MongoDB 3.6 and upwards. It's just a bit more processing and reconstruction:

```
  db.collection('users').aggregate([
    { $match: cond },
    // in legacy form
    { $lookup: {
      from: 'rooms',
      localField: 'user_id',
      foreignField: 'user',
      as: 'rooms'
    }},
    // unwind the output array 
    { $unwind: '$rooms' },
    // lookup for the second collection
    { $lookup: {
      from: 'room_prices',
      localField: 'name',
      foreignField: 'room',
      as: 'rooms.room_prices'
    }},
    // Select array fields with $map
    { $addFields: {
      'rooms': {
        'room_prices': {
          $map: {
            input: '$rooms.room_prices',
            in: {
              morning: '$this.morning',
              afternoon: '$this.afternoon'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
    // now group back to 'users' data
    { $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      name: { $first: '$name' },
      username: { $first: '$username' },
      // same for any other fields, then $push 'rooms'
      rooms: { $push: '$rooms' }
    }}
  ])
```

That's a bit more overhead mostly from usage of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and also noting that the "field selection" does actually mean you did return the "whole documents" from `room_prices` *"first"*, and only after that was complete can you select the fields.

So there are advantages to the newer syntax, but it still could be done with earlier versions if you wanted to.

Comment: the matching data is with `room` object ID from `room_price`, but it's ok. thank you @Neil